# jQuery: complete handler with minimum time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that loads content using `.load()` (but it could use anything).  Sometimes the content loads so fast that the transition animations I use don't look very good, in fact its quite off-putting.  I would like to add a minimum time between the transitions so that if the content loads very quickly itll still wait the minimum time (say 500 ms).

My code currently looks like this, is there a nice jQuery way of doing this?

```
$("body").on("click","a[href]",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    // Do pre load animation (removed for clarity)
    $("#rightpanel").load($(this).attr("href"), function () {
        // Do post load animation (removed for clarity)
        History.pushState(null, null, href);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer involving promises :

```
// suggestion 1
// wait for both pre-load animation and load to complete :

$.when(
    $('.gizmo').slideUp(),
    $("#rightpanel").load($(this).attr("href"))
).done(function(){
    $('.gizmo').stop().slideDown();
    History.pushState(null, null, href);
});


// suggestion 2
// add a "500ms promise" :

function delay(time) {
   var dfd = $.Deferred();
   setTimeout(function(){ dfd.resolve() }, time);
   return dfd.promise();
}

$.when( delay(500),  $("#rightpanel").load($(this).attr("href")) ).done(function(){
    //post load stuff
});
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YvZK6/) to play with.

---

As Chris correctly pointed out in the comments, the above code will not work with `.load()` : `.load()` applies to a jQuery selection, and returns the selected set instead of the underlying ajax promise.

The above code will work if you use `$.ajax`, `$.get`, `$.post` or other global jQuery functions,
or you can create an extra promise :

```
var loadData = $.Deferred();
$('#rightpanel').load($(this).attr('href'), function(){ loadData.resolve() });

$.when( delay(500), loadData ).done( ... )
```

Comment: Actually this doesnt work for the AJAX request, it doesnt wait for it to finish...

Comment: Turns out `load()` wont work but `$.get` does - must be the way they deal with promises